# Get time slots based on multiple workshops

Tags: python, algorithm, sql, django

I have a list of Workshops, each having open days (Monday, Tuesday etc.) and open time and close time (which will be same for each day). Now, Based on the current time, I need to find out next 7 days available slots. A slot is of 2 hour and is available if any of the workshop is open in that 2 hour time. The first slot of each day will start at the open_time (nearest to hour time for eg. if open_time is 09:23:54 then first slot start time will be 10:00:00) of workshop opens first on that day.

My solution so far is to have a `Workshop` table which has `off_days`, `open_at`, `close_at`, `name` columns. There is another table which is `WorkshopHolidays` which has `holiday_date`, `workshop_id`.

```
class Workshop(models.Model):
    DAY_CHOICES = (
        (0,'Monday'),
        (1,'Tuesday'),
        (2,'Wednesday'),
        (3,'Thursday'),
        (4,'Friday'),
        (5,'Saturday'),
        (6,'Sunday')
    )
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255,null=True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=1024)
    open_at = models.TimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    close_at = models.TimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    off_days = MultiSelectField(choices=DAY_CHOICES,null=True,blank=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)


class WorkshopHoliday(CreatedAtAbstractBase):
    workshop = models.ForeignKey(Workshop)
    holiday_date = models.DateField()
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

Now given a datetime, I need to find what are the two hour slots available for next seven days. If any one store is open in a slot, that slot should be part of the output.

The way I am approaching the problem now is following:

```
def get_slots():
    current_time = timezone.now()
    workshops = Workshop.objects.all()
    slots = {}
    for i in range(1,7):
        curdate = current_time.date()
        day = current_time.weekday()
        curdate_dict = {'start_time':None, 'end_time':None}
        for workshop in workshops:
            off_days = workshop.off_days if workshop.off_days else ''
            if day in off_days:
                continue
            wh = WorkshopHoliday.objects.filter(holiday_date=curdate,active=True)
            if wh:
                continue
            start_time = curdate_dict.get('start_time')
            if start_time:
                if start_time > current_time.time() and start_time > workshop.open_at and workshop.open_at > current_time.time():
                    start_time = workshop.open_at
            elif workshop.open_at > current_time.time():
                    start_time = workshop.open_at
            curdate_dict['start_time'] = start_time
            end_time = curdate_dict.get('end_time')
            if end_time:
                if end_time > current_time.time() and end_time < workshop.close_at and workshop.close_at > current_time.time():
                    end_time = workshop.open_at
            elif workshop.open_at > current_time.time():
                    end_time = workshop.open_at
            curdate_dict['end_time'] = end_time
        slots[curdate] = curdate_dict
        current_time.replace(hour=0,minute=0,second=0)
        current_time = current_time + timezone.timedelta(days=1)
```

Please suggest if there could be a better way to approach this problem (may be a better SQL query or algorithm). Also, please point out if there is some scenario in which this will give incorrect result.

Comment: Please do not update the code in your question to incorporate feedback from answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Comment: As mentioned by Matthias Ettinger already: Please do not update your code in answered questions. Instead you may want to ask a new question

Comment: @Vogel612 I thought I can add the updated code separately.

Comment: @Anuj If you want to post an updated code, you can either post an answer explaining what you changed and how it improves upon the original; or post a new question with the new code and indicate that it is a follow-up.

Comment: (`thought I can add the updated code [in a separate code block]` Not in a non-new question, and never after the first substantial answer. Besides, it is difficult for a casual reader to interpret `way I am approaching the problem now`. Accepted are links to web code repositories, self-answers and, after a suitable amount of time (a week?) and/or changes, a cross-linked follow-up question.)

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify the creation of `DAY_CHOICES` using the `calendar` module:

```
DAY_CHOICES = tuple(enumerate(calendar.day_name))
```

this has the advantage of using the right locale, if need be.

---

You can reduce going back and forth between Python and your SQL backend using prefetching of objects, instead of querying each time you need something. Django offers the [`prefetch_related`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.prefetch_related) operation:

```
workshops = Workshop.objects.prefetch_related(
    Prefetch(
        'workshopholiday_set',
        queryset=WorkshopHoliday.objects.filter(
            holiday_date__ge=start_date,
            holiday_date__le=start_date + timezone.timedelta(days=7),
            active=True),
        to_attr='holidays_for_the_week'))
```

Where `start_date` is `timezone.now().date()`. This way, you get a list of every `WorkshopHoliday` for the upcoming week associated to the current workshop into `workshop.holidays_for_the_week`. You can test if the current date is in there with:

```
if curdate in {h.holiday_date for h in workshop.holidays_for_the_week}:
    continue
```

I would also advise to exchange the two `for` loops so you don't compute the set of holiday dates seven time for the same workshop.

---

`curdate_dict` is not necessary. You can replace

```
curdate_dict = {'start_time': None, 'end_time': None}
```

by

```
start_time, end_time = None, None
```

and remove all `curdate_dict.get(…)` and `curdate_dict[…] = …`. You just need to `slots[curdate] = {'start_time': start_time, 'end_time': end_time}` then, which will improve the memory management as well.

---

```
current_time.replace(hour=0, minute=0, second=0)
```

does nothing: the `replace` method returns a new `datetime` instance and since you’re not assigning it, you’re just wasting time.

---

```
for i in range(1, 7):
```

First of, `i` is never used: you should write `_` instead to indicate that. Second, `range(1, 7)` produces 6 values. So you will perform your computations for today and the 5 next days. If you wished to compute your hours for a whole week, you should have written

```
for _ in range(7):
```

instead.

I also advise you to get the "counter" near that line. This is so the reader can grasp your intent more easily:

```
def get_slots():
    starting_time = timezone.now()
    start_date = starting_time.date()
    workshops = Workshop.objects.prefetch_related(
        Prefetch(
            'workshopholiday_set',
            queryset=WorkshopHoliday.objects.filter(
                holiday_date__ge=start_date,
                holiday_date__le=start_date + timezone.timedelta(days=7),
                active=True),
            to_attr='holidays_for_the_week'))
    slots = {}
    for day in range(7):
        current_time = starting_time + timezone.timedelta(days=day)
        …
```

Comment: workshop.holidays_for_the_week is a list. So cannot apply filter to it.

Comment: @Anuj Oh, sorry about that, my django is a bit old. Will adapt the answer shortly. Anyway you should be able to transform that list of `WorkshopHoliday` into a list of their `holiday_date` and use `if curdate in holidays_for_the_week`.

Comment: Thanks. Anyway, do you have any suggestions about the algorithm. May be you can suggest a better one.

Comment: @Anuj I tried to understand exactly what you were trying to achieve but failed. Maybe you could add this kind of detail into your question to help. As far as I got, you’re trying to compute the range of hours when every workshop is open for the upcomming week. But I don't quite get the requirement for `current_time.time()` comming into play.

Comment: I have updated the code. I have a list of Workshops, each having open_days (Monday, Tuesday etc.) and open_time and close_time (which will be same for each day). Now, Based on the current time, I need to find out next 7 days available slots. A slot is of 2 hour and is available if any of the workshop is open in that 2 hour time. The first slot of each day will start at the open_time (nearest to hour time for eg. if open_time is 09:23:54 then first slot start time will be 10:00:00) of workshop opens first on that day.

How to find all the available slots?

Comment: @Anuj Should slot always start on even hours or can they start on odd hours as well ?